# How to rotate a square so that it's a given width

Tags: geometry, triangles

I've struck up against what feels like a simple problem, but one I - for the life of me- can't figure out.

If you have a rectangle, with sides $a$ and $b$, it's exactly $b$ wide. However, when you rotate it, the space it takes up in it's width (in the $x$ dimension) get more, until the space needed is as wide as the hypothenuse at a rotation of 45°. So far so intuitive.

However, how can I calculate **just how much** I need to rotate said rectangle, to take up exactly a given space?

In the image below, you can see I have a rectangle that $120$mm wide and $40$mm tall. How much do I need to rotate it, so that it's "width" is exactly $120$mm?

[image]

Comment: You have two lengths to add up, one of which is $b\cos \alpha$, the other being $a \cos (\pi - \pi/2 - \alpha) = a\sin \alpha$

Comment: You don't have to rotate it ! It is already 120mm wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments we need that

$$120 \cos \alpha +40 \cos (90-\alpha)=120$$

$$120 \cos \alpha +40 \sin \alpha=120$$

$$3 \cos \alpha + \sin \alpha=3$$

which leads to $\alpha =0$ (trivial solution) or $\alpha = 2\arctan \frac13\approx 36,9°$

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: In this solution, which of the 120s are for the box and which are for the space?  For example, if the 120mm-wide box needed to fit through a 100mm width instead of 120mm, how would these equations change?

Comment: @alexpeters The 120 on the RHS are for the space.